# Why pyinstaller can't find error attribute of win32api

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I've built a python program and now I want to make an exe file from it.
But when I insert `pyinstaller something.py --onefile --windowed --icon=icon.png` in command line it shows:

```
 File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 534, in assemble
    icon.CopyIcons(tmpnm, self.icon)
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 232, in CopyIcons
    except win32api.error as W32E:
AttributeError: module 'win32ctypes.pywin32.win32api' has no attribute 'error'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you provide your code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in the same problem trying to bind a png file as icon via pyinstaller.

Simply you have to convert png to ico format, than building will work.
If you already have a spec file you can add **icon='icon_name.ico'** in EXE tuple

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='your_app_name',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          icon='logo.ico') <----------
```

This worked fine for me, hoping it helps you too.